# What's the order class of T(n) = n(T(n−1) + n) with T(1)=1?

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

This recurrence basically comes from the typical solution to N-queens problem. Some people say the complexity is `O(n)` while giving recurrence `T(n) = n(T(n−1) + n)`. But from what I can tell, this concludes `O((n+1)!)`, which is surely different from `O(n!)` asymptotically.

By induction,

If `T(k) <= ck!`,
Then, `T(n) <= n*c(n-1)! + n*n = cn! + n*n`. Thus we don't have `T(n) <= cn!`.

On the other hand,

If `T(k) <= c(k+1)!`,
Then, `T(n) <= n*cn! + n*n <= n*cn! + cn! = c(n+1)!`.

Is this correct? If so, what's the correct way to prove it(other ways than induction is also OK)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U(k)=\frac{T(k)}{k!}$.  Then 
$$U(n)=U(n-1)+\frac{n}{(n-1)!}=U(n-1)+\frac1{(n-1)!}+\frac1{(n-2)!}\\
<U(1)+2e-1\\
T(n)<2e(n!)$$

Comment: Thanks! But what's wrong with the induction?

Comment: U(k) is the ratio between $T(k)$ and $k!$, so it is the $c$ value in your equation.  and it keeps getting bigger.  So the c that works for k won't work for k+1.  But the c will always remain less than $2e$ because it increases by less and less each time.

Comment: The first equation should be: `U(n) = U(n-1) + n^2/n!`

Comment: Whoops, yes, corrected now.